# android volley ImageLoader NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView iv1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getImage("http://b.hiphotos.baidu.com/pic/w%3D310/sign=9b24260fd53f8794d3ff4e2fe21a0ead/f636afc379310a55ba781b43b64543a98226102c.jpg");
    }


    public void getImage(String url){
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        final LruCache<String, Bitmap> lruCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);
        ImageCache imageCache = new ImageCache() {

            @Override
            public void putBitmap(String arg0, Bitmap arg1) {
                lruCache.put(arg0, arg1);
            }

            @Override
            public Bitmap getBitmap(String arg0) {
                return lruCache.get(arg0);
            }
        };
        ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue, imageCache);
        ImageListener listener = imageLoader.getImageListener(iv1, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        System.out.println("listener:"+listener);
        System.out.println("imageLoader"+imageLoader);
        imageLoader.get(url, listener);
    }
}
```

Error:

> 04-16 21:39:21.493: E/AndroidRuntime(3454): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> 04-16 21:39:21.493: E/AndroidRuntime(3454):   at
>   com.wise.volleydemo.MainActivity.getImage(MainActivity.java:79)

Comment: Add some text to describe your problem. Not only the code

Comment: Im not sure .Move    iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1); after set content view. Please explain the issue you are facing

Comment: i have got the mistake by answer,thank you for everyone

Answer (score 1):

Move

```
iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
```

after

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

In the current code, you are trying to find your ImageView in your view hierarchy when the view hierarchy hasn't been initialised yet. The activity's root view is initialised in the setContentView() method. So you should call that before trying to access any other views.